# Excel File is getting Corrupted while renaming the Existing excel file with Current date and Time?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I am renaming the existing Excel file using below code, Excel File is getting generated with Current Time Stamp but when I am trying the open the renamed Excel file, I am not able to Open it. It is showing Workbook is Corrupted.

Please Find Out where is the Error in the Below code. Why Excel File is getting Corrupted?

```
package BrokenLink;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


    public class CreateExcelFile {


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
       
        
            //new File("C:\\Users\\skumari1\\eclipse-workspace\\AlarmTest\\Generics").mkdir();
                CreateFileRenameExisting("NewBook.xlsx");


            }
        
        


        //Rename an existing file and create a new file
        public static void CreateFileRenameExisting(String filename)
        {
            //get current project path
            String filePath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
            //create a new file
            File file=new File(filePath+"\\"+filename);
            try {
                if(!file.exists()) {
                
                    Workbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook();


                    FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream(filename);


                    wb1.write(fileOut1);


                    fileOut1.close();
                    //file.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("File is created");
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    File backupFile=new File(filePath+"\\"+ Validatedate()  +  file.getName());
                    System.out.println("File already exist and backup file is created");
                    file.renameTo(backupFile);
                }
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        public static String Validatedate() {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH_mm_ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String date1= dateFormat.format(date);
            // System.out.println("Current date and time is " +date1);
             return date1;
        }
        


        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you able to open file that is created before it is renamed? How are you creating the file, through same code?

Comment: No File is already created ,only i am renaming with this code and yes i am able to open the file before it is renamed.

Comment: I am waiting for the response, can you please reply as soon as possible , Actually its urgent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add workbook code in else part too.
As you are simply renaming the file with File object may be the reason your excel is getting corrupted.
Add Workbook code in else part and also close your workbook instance once all operations are done.

Comment: ya my code is working fine now, Actually for one Excel file only one time its getting updated with current Time Stamp , but if i am trying to run the same code the file is getting Corrupted, this is because the excel filepath got changed after renaming.

Comment: Hello, I need one suggestion the current  filepath which is i am using for rename with current Timestamp and the filepath  i am using for TestReport can be same?Because if i am giving the same filelocation again the Excel file is getting corrupted? Is this because the Test report file location is already in use and we cannot provide the same location. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use same file path but two process cannot access same file at one time. So if you are trying to use same file at same time at two places definitely there will be errors or exceptions.